# when I enable hair dynamics hair explodes

Tags: particles, hair, dynamic

whenever I try to enable hair dynamics the hair explodes, I tried to mess with hair dynamics options, but it doesn't really make any difference, I also baked the hair but it didn't matter, I want to make hair moves with wind but dynamics won't help me, it doesn't have anything with wind It's all about hair dynamics, could anyone help ?

here's the project link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xII_q6vWS8JP3StsEEPClW2azAUoB4yg/view?usp=sharing

here's it at first
[image]

and here after I play the animation
[image]

Comment: I'm no expert for hair and I really couldn't find a setting to change so that it behaves normal. The only thing I could do was delete the edit and then I combed the hair again to give it a new edit. After that it worked fine. So there seems to be something wrong with the particle edit.

Comment: yep I did as you said, I deleted the hair and did it again